# Ubuntu Mate support

Tags: software-recommendation

I just installed Ubuntu Mate on a HP 386 laptop, however I was told on a FB linux group that Ubuntu Mate is no longer supported or updated. Is this correct? If so, should I look for another OS to use on my outdated and underpowered laptop? Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu MATE is fully supported...on 64-bit systems. Your "*HP 386*" suggests that yours is a 32-bit system. If true, Ubuntu MATE 18.04, the final 32-bit release, will work, but support for that release does indeed end quite soon. Note that Ubuntu claims to be *easy to install*, and *easy for beginners to use*. It does not claim to be *lightweight*, nor does it claim global compatibility with all hardware. If you are indeed running 32-bit, sorry, Suggestion: Debian can be prodded into a good 32-bit Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

That is a fully false claim. Ubuntu MATE continues to be fully supported. What is more, Ubuntu MATE is a flavor of very high quality and innovation, arguably one of the best MATE linux distributions in existence. The whole team, and especially its devoted leader, Martin Wimpress, deserves a lot of credit for the stellar quality that this Ubuntu flavour has reached.